# Convert array of objects into object with property values grouped by key name

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to do it dynamically if we have more objects in input data?

I have dataset array with multiple objects inside it, and objects can be any number.
and I have to convert this data into newDataset object with dynamic array inside of it, this array of number dependence on dataset array's objects. I have done this if we have known number of dataset array's objects. for example: see below.

```js
// Input data have dynamic more objects.
var dataset = [
  {
    date: "1 Jan 2020",
    data1: 44,
    data2: 40,
  },
  {
    date: "2 Jan 2020",
    data1: 37,
    data2: 60,
  },
  {
    date: "3 Jan 2020",
    data1: 75,
    data2: 90,
  },
];

var newDataset = {};

// // Output data should be in this form.
// var newDataset = {
//   date: ["1 Jan 2020", "2 Jan 2020", "3 Jan 2020"],
//   data1: [44, 37, 75],
//   data2: [40, 60, 90],
// };


// write your code below

var date = [];
var data1 = [];
var data2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
  date.push(dataset[i].date);
  data1.push(dataset[i].data1);
  data2.push(dataset[i].data2);
}

newDataset.date = date;
newDataset.data1 = data1;
newDataset.data2 = data2;
console.log(newDataset);

//end of your code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Map` object

```js
var dataset = [
  { date: "1 Jan 2020", data1: 44, data2: 40 },
  { date: "2 Jan 2020", data1: 37, data2: 60 },
  { date: "3 Jan 2020", data1: 75, data2: 90 }
];

const myMap = new Map();

dataset.forEach(obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    myMap.has(k) ? myMap.get(k).push(v) : myMap.set(k, [v]);
  })
});

console.log(Object.fromEntries(myMap.entries()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer is much easier for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Following seems to work dynamically:

```js
const src = [{date:"1 Jan 2020",data1:44,data2:40,},{date:"2 Jan 2020",data1:37,data2:60,},{date:"3 Jan 2020",data1:75,data2:90,},],

    rebuild = arr =>
      arr.reduce((r, o) => (
        Object.keys(o).forEach(key => (
          !r[key] && (r[key] = []), 
          r[key].push(o[key])
        )), 
        r
      ), {})
          
console.log(rebuild(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although, you have already taken an answer as accepted, here I've a bit more abstract solution for you. Let's say, what if the objects in `dataset` are not strictly structured?, meaning some of these objects may have properties that you don't want in your `newDataset`.
This following solution gives you power to filter the properties as you need.

```js
const dataSet = [
    { date: "1 Jan 2020", data1: 44, data2: 40 },
    { date: "2 Jan 2020", data1: 37, data2: 60 },
    { date: "3 Jan 2020", data1: 75, data2: 90, unnecessary: 939393 },
  ];
const newDataset = {date: [], data1: [], data2: []} // if you need only these 3 properties.
const createNewDataset = (givenDataset) =>
    givenDataset.reduce(
      (builOn, current) => (
        Object.entries(current).forEach(
          ([key, value]) => (Array.isArray(builOn[key]) ? builOn[key].push(value): null)
        ),
        builOn
      ),
      newDataset
    );

console.log(createNewDataset(dataSet));
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary item is work fine, but it is not dynamic for more data item.

Comment: You meant more properties in `dataset's` object? Actually there should have no silver bullet for this problem's solution.