# How to get a new array from an array with nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the below array:

```
 var data = [
   { "id":"id1", "key":"2020-07-15T06:32:44.08Z", "value":["E19","on"] },
   { "id":"id2", "key":"2020-07-15T06:32:44.08Z", "value":["E20","on"] },
   { "id":"id3", "key":"2020-07-15T06:32:44.08Z", "value":["E21","off"] },
   { "id":"id1", "key":"2020-07-15T06:33:44.08Z", "value":["E19","on"] },
   { "id":"id4", "key":"2020-07-15T06:34:44.08Z", "value":["E19","faulty"] },
   { "id":"id5", "key":"2020-07-15T06:35:44.08Z", "value":["E19","on"] }
  ];
```

I want this data to be converted to the below form to be used on Google charts:

```
var expectedData = [
    ["time","on","off","faulty"],
    ["06:32:44",2,1,0],
    ["06:33:44",2,1,0],  //here the count is same because E19 is only records for this time which is 
                      //already marked as 'on' in the before time stamp. Hence no change is required.

    ["06:34:44",1,1,1], //E19 has been changed to 'faulty', hence 'on' is reduced by 1 and 'faulty' 
                        //increased by 1
    ["06:35:44",2,1,0]  //E19 is changed back to 'on' hence 'on' is increased by 1 and 'faulty' 
                        //reduced by 1
 ];
```

Can someone please help me with javascript code to sort this data to be used in my React Google charts?

I have written the below code so far:

```
    const data = [
        { "id":"id1", "key":"2020-07-15T06:32:44.08Z", "value":["GigabyteEthernet4/0/19","on"] },
        { "id":"id2", "key":"2020-07-15T06:32:44.08Z", "value":["GigabyteEthernet4/0/20","on"] },
        { "id":"id3", "key":"2020-07-15T06:32:44.08Z", "value":["GigabyteEthernet4/0/21","off"] },
        { "id":"id1", "key":"2020-07-15T06:33:44.08Z", "value":["GigabyteEthernet4/0/19","on"] },
        { "id":"id4", "key":"2020-07-15T06:34:44.08Z", "value":["GigabyteEthernet4/0/19","faulty"] },
        { "id":"id5", "key":"2020-07-15T06:35:44.08Z", "value":["GigabyteEthernet4/0/19","on"] }
    ];

    // var poeObj = new Object();
    let t;
    var newArray= [];
    var newData = data.map((item,el)=>{
        t= new Date(item.key);
        var poeObj = Object.assign({},el)
        poeObj.time= t.toLocaleTimeString();
        poeObj.intfName= item.value[0];
        poeObj.state= item.value[1];
        if(poeObj.intfName)
        console.log(poeObj);
        return poeObj;
    })
    console.log(newData)

    var newData1 = [
        {time: "12:02:44 PM", intfName: "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", state: "on"},
        {time: "12:02:44 PM", intfName: "GigabyteEthernet4/0/20", state: "on"},
        {time: "12:02:44 PM", intfName: "GigabyteEthernet4/0/21", state: "off"},
        {time: "12:03:44 PM", intfName: "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", state: "on"},
        {time: "12:04:44 PM", intfName: "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", state: "faulty"},
        {time: "12:05:44 PM", intfName: "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", state: "on"}
    ]

    var uniqueData = newData1.reduce((arr,item)=>{
        var newArr = [];
        newArr.push(item.time, item.intfName, item.state);
        console.log(newArr)
        arr.push(newArr)
        return arr;
    },[])
    console.log(uniqueData)
   //uniqueData= [
        ["12:02:44 PM", "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", "on"],
        ["12:02:44 PM", "GigabyteEthernet4/0/20", "on"],
        ["12:02:44 PM", "GigabyteEthernet4/0/21", "off"],
        ["12:03:44 PM", "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", "on"],
        ["12:04:44 PM", "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", "faulty"],
        ["12:05:44 PM", "GigabyteEthernet4/0/19", "on"]
    ];
```

After all these code, I have got the formatted array as the above 'uniqueData'. But not sure if this is the efficient way. Although, I idn't reach my final expected output which is 'expectedData' mentioned in the begining. Can some one please advise me on this?

Comment: have you looked into using javascript `reduce` method ? i honestly not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Provide your attempted solution and indicate where you get stuck

Comment: Check out below link may be it will help you. [Transform array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812797/convert-array-of-objects-into-object-with-property-values-grouped-by-key-name)

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the content of your item in an array by using Array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

If I have the following:

```
var data = [
   { "id":"1", "title":"Lorem ipsum" },
   { "id":"2", "title":"Test title" },
   { "id":"3", "title":"another title" },
];
```

I can do:

```
// .map will traverse each item and we pass a function on how we want to deal with new item structure
data.map((item) => {
   // I will convert individual item to this format: Array[id, title]
   return [item.id, item.title]
})
```

This will return

```
[
    [1, "Lorem ipsum"],
    [2, "Test title"],
    [3, "another title"],
]
```

In your question you have a different item structure in your array `["time","on","off","faulty"]`

by getting the output from .map you just append using [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) `["time","on","off","faulty"]` from your .map result.

```
// This will append ["time","on","off","faulty"] in the first index of array
result.splice(0, 0, ["time","on","off","faulty"])
```

Using *[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)* is also possible

I can do:

```
// Reduce also works by merging items, it can take two parameters (function, initial value)
data.reduce((accumulated, currentItem) => {
   accumulated.push([currentItem.id, currentItem.title])
}, [["time","on","off","faulty"]])
```

This will have similar output with .map, the difference is you can put ahead the `["time","on","off","faulty"]` in your new array without doing splice.

Comment: Well this might be a solution, but could this be refactored by using javascript `reduce` ? i ask this from a students perspective.

Comment: `reduce` will merge all items into one result (eg: sum of an array of numbers).
Given the example data from the question, I can't think of alternative approach on using `.reduce` to get the desired output.
While .map allows you to modify individual items in your array and transform it into a different structure, I think this is the efficient solution for me.

Comment: Ok thank you for explaining :) will give it an upvote

Comment: @BARNOWL sorry, I have a second thought about this. I think you can do `reduce` also. let me update my answer in order to justify it.

Comment: @Renesansz, thank you for the above input. But the output you have shown was the object values has been stored as an nested array which is very much required. Also, my output should be the count of each value with 'on' off' 'faulty'